# Next.js & Axios: Delete Method 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: http, axios, next.js, cors

I'm building mini forum feature in my app using Next.js. The forum has a feature where you can delete your forum post if you are the author. I try to make a delete request using the HTML form and axios.delete. It hits the API endpoint properly and surprisingly executes the delete (from a database) yet gives out an error that says 405 Method Not Allowed. I have already read and applied what is written in the [Vercel Docs](https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-to-enable-cors) regarding this issue but to no avail. Code below

**next.config.js**

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    // typescript: true,
    headers: [
        { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
        { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "http://localhost:3000" },
        {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT",
        },
        {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version",
        },
    ],
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

**school-forum/[id].tsx**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import styles from "./index.module.css";
interface Props {
    currentId: number;
}
const ButtonOptions: React.FC<Props> = ({currentId}) => {
    const thisAPI: string = `/school-forum/${currentId}`;
    async function handleDelete(): Promise<void> {
        await axios.delete(thisAPI, {
            data: {
                currentId,
            },
        });
        return void 0;
    }

    return (
        <>
            ...
            <div>
                <form
                    className={styles.optionForms}
                    onSubmit={handleDelete}
                >
                    <h2 className={styles.optionH2Header}>Option Delete</h2>
                    <hr className="horizontalRuleYellow" />
                    <b className={styles.deleteMessage}>
                        Notice: This action cannot be reversed
                    </b>
                    <p className={styles.deleteMessage}>
                        Are you sure you want to proceed to deletion?
                    </p>
                    <hr className="horizontalRuleYellow" />
                    <div className={styles.optionButtons}>
                        <button type="submit">Execute Option</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default ButtonOptions;
```

**api/school-forum/[id].tsx**

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import dbExecute from "../../../_operations/db/db";

export default async function (
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse
): Promise<void> {
    
    if (req.method === "DELETE") {
        try {
            const { currentId } = req.body;
            
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT')
            res.setHeader(
              'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
              'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version'
            )
            
            
            
            const sql: string = `
            DELETE FROM forum_question_table
            WHERE question_id = ?;`;
            await dbExecute(sql, [currentId]);
      // this executes but errors
      
      
            
            res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/school-forum");     
            return void 0;
        } catch (error: unknown) {
            console.log(error);
            console.log("error");
            
            res.status(500).redirect("http://localhost:3000/500");
            return void 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Turns out I can't redirect in the API folder with a delete method since that results in a weird 405 error. So what I did is just `res.status(200).send("")` in the hitted API endpoint and `router.push("/school-forum")` in the front end component for the redirect.

```js
...
const ButtonOptions: React.FC<Props> = ({currentId}) => {
    const thisAPI: string = `/school-forum/${currentId}`;
    async function handleDelete(): Promise<void> {
        await axios.delete(thisAPI, {
            data: {
                currentId,
            },
        });
        router.push("/school-forum")
        return void 0;
    }
    
    ...
```

then remove `res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/school-forum");`

Comment: Why can't you redirect to the API's folder?